# ORACLE - Missing keyword when creating table help

Tags: oracle

I am trying to complete a project but i keep getting "missing keyword" error when i try to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE SKILLS (
SkillsID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
ConsultantID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
ExpertiseID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
MonthsExperience INT NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT SkillsPK PRIMARY KEY (SkillsID),

CONSTRAINT SkillsConsultFK FOREIGN KEY(ConsultantID)
                REFERENCES CONSULTANTS(ConsultantID)
                ON UPDATE NO ACTION                
                ON DELETE CASCADE,


CONSTRAINT SkillsExpertiseFK FOREIGN KEY(ExpertiseID)
                REFERENCES EXPERTISE(ExpertiseID)
                ON UPDATE NO ACTION
                ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Please! all help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `ON UPDATE NO ACTION`.  Since there is no `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in Oracle so there's no need to specify `NO ACTION`.

Comment: Did you remove both of them?  Without those two lines the statement works for me.  Also, depending on your environment you may need to remove the blank lines.  For example, the blank lines would cause a problem with SQL*Plus.

Comment: If you're using SQL*Plus you can configure it to ignore blank lines by running `set sqlblanklines on`